# Trying to Increase Spawn Rate of Obstacles in Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a Canvas game based on an example on W3schools. I currently have it set so that every 100 frames, an obstacle will spawn. I want to make it so that upon reaching a certain amount of frames in the game, for example 500, the obstacles will switch to spawn every 50 frames instead. I've tried a few different methods, all currently commented out, and none of them work. I can't figure out how to get the  code to recognize when it has reached x amount of frames or how to decrease the amount of frames in between each obstacle's spawn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
    <script>

    let myGamePiece;
    let myObstacles = [];
    let myScore;
    let topOrBottom = 0;

    function startGame() {
        myGamePiece = new component(20, 20, "blue", 10, 380);
        myScore = new component("20px", "Arial", "black", 280, 40, "text")
        myGameArea.start();
    }

    let myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 600;
            this.canvas.height = 400;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.frameNo = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
            },
        clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.score = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;   
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function() {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            if (this.type == "text") {
                ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }
        this.newPos = function() {
            if ((this.y+this.height) == myGameArea.canvas.height) {
                this.y = 0;
            } else if (this.y == 0) {
                this.y = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
            }

        }
        this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
            let myleft = this.x;
            let myright = this.x + (this.width);
            let mytop = this.y;
            let mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            let otherleft = otherobj.x;
            let otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);        
            let othertop = otherobj.y;       
            let otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            let crash = true;  
            if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {        
                crash = false;        
            }
            return crash;
        }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
        let x, y, height, topOrBottom, distance, minHeight, maxHeight, minDistance, maxDistance;
        for (i= 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
                stopButton();
                return;
            }
        }

        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(100)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            y = myGameArea.canvas.height;
            topOrBottom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
            minDistance = 200;
            maxDistance = 300;
            distance = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxDistance-minDistance+1)+minDistance);

            if (topOrBottom == 1) {
                myObstacles.push(new component(10, 30, "orange", x, 0));
            } else if (topOrBottom == 2) {
                myObstacles.push(new component(10, 30, "orange", x, myGameArea.canvas.height-30));
            }
        }



        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -10;
            myObstacles[i].update();
        }

        myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
        myScore.update();
        myGamePiece.update();

    }

    function everyinterval(n) {
        if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
        return false;
    }

    /*if (myGameArea.frameNo > 300) {
        (myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 0.5 == 0;
    }*/

    function restart() {
        document.location.href = "";
    }

    function stopButton() {
        let button = document.getElementById("switch");
        button.disabled = true;
    }

    function speedUp() {
        //(myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 0.5 == 0;
        myGameArea.n = 0.5;
    }

    /*if (myGameArea.frameNo > 300) {
        speedUp();
    }*/

</script>
<br>
<button id="switch" onmousedown="myGamePiece.newPos()" onmouseup="speedUp()">SWITCH</button>
<button onmousedown="restart()">RESTART</button>
```

Comment: please, tell me the exact sequence of spawn you want... like for example, first after 100, second after 50 third after 25 ecc ecc

Comment: Start at every 100 frames, then at every 50, then 40, then 30, then 25, then 20, then 15, then 10.

Answer (score 0):

the step is defined inside the if, and each of those steps will be repeated for `periodForEachStep` times

```
var currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod = 100 
var periodForEachStep = 10;
var currentPeriodStep = 0;
var frames = 0;
```

then update your if statement to

```
frames++;
if (frames == currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod){...}
```

and then inside that if at the end, you have to check if it's time to update `currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod` or the `currentPeriodStep` like so:

```
frames = 0;
if(currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod == 100){
    if(currentPeriodStep < periodForEachStep) currentPeriodStep++;
    else{ 
       currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod = 50;
       currentPeriodStep = 0;
   }
}
else if(currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod<30&& currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod>6){
    if(currentPeriodStep < periodForEachStep) currentPeriodStep++;
    else{ 
       currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod-=5;
       currentPeriodStep = 0;
   }
}
else {
    if(currentPeriodStep < periodForEachStep) currentPeriodStep++;
    else{ 
       currentObjectFramesSpawnPeriod -=10;
       currentPeriodStep = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: This spawns each obstacle once and then stop spawning any altogether, instead of keeping that spawn rate for a set period of frames. I'm also confused with what you said to count the frames from 0 to infinity. I do need that to work because the score is based on the frames, so if you wouldn't mind clarifying that last point it would be very helpful.

Comment: ok, i'll change the answer with those information... but on your comment you haven't said anything about period of time, so i was tinking that after the first 100 frame is spowns an obstacle, then after the next 50, spowns another ecc ecc

Comment: ok, changed the answer in order to not reset the frameNo variables, as soon as you specify the period for each steap, i'll edit the code in order to support also the ''period'' on each step

Comment: try with this... they wil do: each 100 frames * 10 times, then each 50 frames * 10 times, then each 40 frames * 10 times, then each 30 frames * 10 times, then each 25 frames * 10 times ecc ec..

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to be working. Would you be able to post the if statement in its entirety to make sure that I'm formatting it correctly? It's probably a mistake I made lol